# Why ChatGPT output one token at a time?

Tags: transformer, attention, chatgpt, large-language-models

My understanding of the language model is that the output of the model is a tensor. So the whole output should be computed all together. But why ChatGPT like models can output one token at a time like a stream? And the time difference between the output of first and last token is significant.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The output of a GPT model is a probability for each possible next token.

Comment: See https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/38923/why-does-chatgpt-not-give-the-answer-text-all-at-once/38929#38929